# How do I import SlickUtils?

Tags: java, import, javaimports

I'm attempting to import SlickUtils into my project, but I can't figure out how.

For example - to import ArrayList i'd do

```
import java.util.Arraylist;
```

Could someone let me know how to do this with SlickUtils?

Thanks.

Comment: How is `SlickUtils` provided to you? Is this something you created or is it part of a library?

Comment: @hfontanez I believe it's part of a library. It was reccomended to be used on a forum - (my intent is to program a small 2d game on java, ```SlickUtil``` is an importable GUI.) However, I can't find the import at all - nor a potential download.

Comment: You class(es) need to be incorporated into your projects first. See @rhowell's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like an external library, which is not bundled with java. You can do this two ways.

Option one is to manually add this to Jar to your build path. You can look up how to do this with whichever IDE you are using, it should be simple.

Option two is to do this is with a build tool like [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/what-is-maven.html), which I would recommend over the first option if you plan on using more libraries.

Here is the dependency - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/slick-util/slick-util/1.0.0

If you want to add it to your build path manually you can download the jar file from here. If you plan to use it with maven you can copy the text and add it to your POM file. After you can access the JAR in your project you should be able to import it just like any other class.